# \texttt can't show "ij" of babel-dutch' \appendixname in the fonts used bij apa6 man and doc mode

Tags: babel, typewriter, apa6

Using the `apa6` class with the  option `man` or `doc`, and using `[dutch]babel`, `\texttt` drops the "ij" of `\appendixname`.

(The Dutch word for "Appendix" (that `babel` uses)  is "Bijlage".

MWE:

```
%Run with pdflatex
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\shorttitle{foo}
\begin{document}
\appendixname; \texttt{\appendixname}; \texttt{Bijlage}\par

\renewcommand\appendixname{Bijzonder dit}
\appendixname; \texttt{\appendixname}; \texttt{Bijzonder dit}\par

\renewcommand\appendixname{Bijlage}
\appendixname; \texttt{\appendixname}; \texttt{Bijlage}
\end{document}
```

Output of MWE:
[image: Output of the above MWE]

At first I thought it could be because the "ij" is a ligature, bij after redefining it works fine. This only happens in `apa6` class (not `jou`-mode).

Can someone explain this remarkable behaviour to me?
And, is it a bug?

Comment: With T1 font-encoding that `apa6.cls` chooses automatically `\ij` is a separate glyph, but the `lmodern` typewriter font doesn't seem to have it. The solution depends on your use case. If you must have `ij` in `\texttt` you may get away with writing `ij` instead of `\ij`/`"y`, or you just don't use `\texttt`. Or you get a font that has a typewriter `\ij`.

Comment: @moewe That's it. Could you make an answer out of your comment so I can accept.

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition that this is about the ij ligature is correct. If you look at the definition of `\appendixname` (with `\show\appendixname`) you'll find that it is

```
B"ylage
```

The shorthand `"y` is `\ij{}` in text mode, so that you are typesetting

```
B\ij{}lage
```

in the first line of your MWE.

The `apa6` class loads `fontenc` with the `T1` encoding and `lmodern`. In the `T1` encoding `\ij{}` is a glyph in its own right and not just a kerned combination of `i` and `j` (as it is in `OT1`: `\nobreak\hskip\z@skip i\kern-0.02em j\nobreak\hskip\z@skip`). But it seems that the typewriter font of Latin modern does not have the ij-glyph and so you just see nothing in its place.

Depending on your use case you can

- Typeset `\appendixname` in a font different from `\ttfamily`.
- Change `\appendixname` to `Bijlage` instead of `B"ylage`.
- Use a typewriter font with the `ĳ` glyph.

If you write `ij` instead of `"y`/`\ij` in the rest of your document, the second solution might be the preferable for consistency's sake. You may also want to closely inspect `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename` (`L"yst` vs `Lijst`) `\proofname` and `\glossaryname`. Maybe it would be easier to just redefine `\ij` then...